# Unable to force render Context in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state-management, react-memo

Certainly! It sounds like you have a React application with a multiple-page form, where each page's data is stored in a context. When navigating away from the form (e.g., by clicking a link in the navigation bar) and then returning, you want to reset the form to the first page instead of maintaining the current page. Despite attempting to use memo, you're still facing difficulties in achieving this behavior.

Here's a more detailed version of your question:

I'm working on a React application that features a complex, multiple-page form. The form's data is managed through a context, where each page has its own set of state variables. One challenge I'm encountering is ensuring that when a user navigates away from the form, such as by clicking a link in the navigation bar, and subsequently returns, the form resets to the first page.

The structure involves a navigation bar with three links corresponding to different sections of the application. Let's say the user is on the second page of the form, clicks on one of the navigation links, and then returns to the form. In this scenario, I want the form to reset to the first page, with all the state variables in the context being cleared or set to their initial values.

```
export const FormProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [forceRender, setForceRender] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [nights, setNights] = useState(null);
  const [subPage, setSubPage] = useState(1)
  const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
  const [arrivalDepartureList,setArrivalDepartureList] =useState([]);
  const toggleRender = ()=>{
    setForceRender(prevState => !prevState)
  }
  return (
    <FormContext.Provider
      value={{ 
    // FORM EXPORTS
        title, 
        page, setPage, 
        nights, setNights,
        subPage,setSubPage,
        travellerDetails, setTravellerDetails, 
        canSubmit, 
        handleChange, 
        disableBack, disableNext,
        currentState,setCurrentState,
        states,setStates,
        arrivalDepartureList,setArrivalDepartureList,
        days,setDays,
        isLoading,setIsLoading,

    // Force Render
    toggleRender,forceRender
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default FormContext;
```

I've attempted to use the useMemo hook to memoize the context value, but I'm struggling to figure out how to trigger a complete reset of the form when returning to it. The goal is to force a re-render of the entire context, leading to the reset of all the states associated with the form.

How can I achieve this behavior effectively? Are there alternative approaches or best practices for managing the state of a multi-page form within a React context, especially when needing to enforce a reset upon returning to the form?

Comment: It looks like you have come up with an original question, but then used an AI tool to help with writing style. While as far as I know this is perfectly OK, you should *always review the result before posting to be sure the output still accurately reflects your intent*. For example, the first paragraph is not actually part of your question, and could confuse reviewers into thinking you've mistakenly posted an *answer* in the *question* box - which could lead to this getting flagged as "Unclear what you're asking." I would suggest you edit to delete the first paragraph and next sentence after it